# Setting up video for Drupal- to play in popup

Tags: files

I've set up a Drupal website and would like to have video box that pops up when a user clicks a picture graphic. Sounds simple enough, but it turns out it is not straightforward in the land of Drupal, flash, codecs, and iphone... Here's what I'd like:

User clicks a link on my Drupal website, a video box player pops up as a mini-box player for the user to watch in a PC or Mac.
For iphone users, want the ability for them to view video on iPhone (which means it can't be flash).
Here's where I am so far. I recorded a screencast using both Camtasia for Mac and Screenflow. But I don't know which format to encode the video- or how to.

I've read that JW player (long tail video) is a good player because it will play both flash and HTML (good for iPhone), but then also read that Drupal and JWplayer does do a popup video window from a link. Is that true?

So before embarking further, I'd love some input on how to proceed? Which encoding format, how to achieve pop-up video player, and have ability to play on iPhone. Of course all through a Drupal site. Btw- I would be hosting the video on Vimeo, or Amazon's cloudfront.

Comment: For which version of Drupal are you interested?

Comment: Did you find solution? I am searching for vimeo in overlay. Drupal 7

Answer (score 2):

Video is hard. One thing to think about is that if you are going to use Vimeo then you don't need to worry about formats since Vimeo will handle that on upload (and the player, and the HTML5). My personal preference would be to use [embedded media field](http://drupal.org/project/emfield), and the [media:vimeo](http://drupal.org/project/media_vimeo) module.

Then you end up with the video as a cck field and you can use something like colorbox to give you your popup.

Comment: I assumed that this question was targeted at D6.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the OSM Media Player: http://www.mediafront.org/project/osmplayer

I use it to play video in an online store, where the videos are hosted at the store, but the OSM Player works with remotely hosted videos just fine. AND I've noticed with my self-hosted videos that if I encode the videos in iPhone format, the OSM Player does something where the videos play on every device and OS I've tried: OS X, iOS, various flavors of Windows, both an Android phone and tablet worked, and also Ubuntu and Redhat Linux played the videos fine.

I play the videos both on a "static page" (built using their standard player in a block, and that as a Panel in a Panels page) and in a LightBox2 "popup" just as suggested by Kiamlaluno.

I do this is D6, not tried the setup in D7 yet... Also, there is a batch-processing capable version of QuickTime 7 Pro (OS X only) out there that correctly encodes these videos in the iPhone h26whatever format, enabling one to process gigs of video without having to sit there and babysit the process.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, try this [module](http://drupal.org/project/video_embed_field_overlay) ; install it with the dom window librarie

Answer (score 0):

use [video_embed_fiels](https://drupal.org/project/video_embed_field) and colorbox to make popup video. if you make a popup video gallery with image preset you use also [image cache actions](http://drupal.org/project/) for good image preset for the video.